# Is this an example of Modal interchange?

Tags: theory, cadence, functional-harmony, modal

The section I'm referring to is circled in red. [image]

The piece is in `D♭ major`. And I think here it's in `F mixolydian`, as both `Cmin7` and `F7` are in F mixolydian. Also, this part is the end of a phrase and sounds quite finalised before it moves back to the opening phrase which begins on `G♭M7` (chord 4 of D♭). Why does it sound so finalised?

The piece is *Merry Christmas Mr Lawrence*..

Comment: Are you sure Fmaj7 is in F Mixolydian? F Mix. contains all the notes from Bb major. That key has Eb in it, not Enat.

Comment: @Tim sorry I meant fdom7, I put major 7 accidentally. Just made the change thanks!